# Rails phusion confusion - source file is missing, but which one? how can I find out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I am finding phusion's error message to be very confusing, maybe I am not looking in the right places but almost every error I stumble into I get the same sort of message.

**Looking for some guidance!**

I SSH'd into the server, and ran a bundle install just to make sure my capistrano missed a step, I also did a rake db:setup and rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production.

This error message seems to be very criptic, I dont' even see a hint as to which file is missing?

I'm running ubuntu, nginx, phusion, ree, in a rails 3 application:

```
Error message:
uninitialized constant Bundler
Exception class:
NameError
Application root:
/home/sshuser/domains/example.com/current
Backtrace:
#   File    Line    Location
0   /home/sshuser/domains/example.com/releases/20101205022037/config/boot.rb    9   
1   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in `gem_original_require'
2   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in `require'
3   /home/sshuser/domains/example.com/releases/20101205022037/config/application.rb 1   
4   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in `gem_original_require'
5   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in `require'
6   /home/sshuser/domains/example.com/releases/20101205022037/config/environment.rb 2   
7   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in `gem_original_require'
8   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in `require'
9   config.ru   3   
10  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb   46  in `instance_eval'
11  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb   46  in `initialize'
12  config.ru   1   in `new'
13  config.ru
```

My setup_load_paths.rb looks like:

```
if ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'] && ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'].include?('rvm')
  begin
    rvm_path     = File.dirname(File.dirname(ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME']))
    rvm_lib_path = File.join(rvm_path, 'lib')
    $LOAD_PATH.unshift rvm_lib_path
    require 'rvm'
    RVM.use_from_path! File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  rescue LoadError
    # RVM is unavailable at this point.
    raise "RVM ruby lib is currently unavailable."
  end
end
```

And my boot.rb looks like:

require 'rubygems'

```
# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
gemfile = File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
begin
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = gemfile
  require 'bundler'
  Bundler.setup
rescue Bundler::GemNotFound => e
  STDERR.puts e.message
  STDERR.puts "Try running `bundle install`."
  exit!
end if File.exist?(gemfile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from your `config/setup_load_paths.rb`. I am guessing that you use this file to set up passenger with RVM support. I would also guess that it includes two bundler includes, something like:

```
require 'bundler'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.setup
```

…which should now just be:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup
```

Just guesses… if that's not the case, edit and put the contents of your setup_load_paths.rb in the question.

Comment: So I assume you've commented out the lower portion and left the first part. On your server what does `bundle -v` say? And is there a different version in the rvm gemset that passenger is using?

Comment: going into irb, and doing 'require bunder' I get the same error.  How do I set my GEM_HOME in a web app?

Comment: I got the GEM_HOME potential solution from: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3990-no-such-file-to-load-bundler-loaderror-in-rails-300beta

Comment: I have a .rvmrc in my root, so both are using the same ruby + gemset.

Comment: I'm running rails 3.0.3 btw, and REE

Comment: Sam, but the 'lower portion' you mean everything below # Or bunder 0.9?

Comment: I meant the bundler 1.0 beta part.. you have the right one. The GEM_HOME is probably the right ticket. I set mine in the apache VirtualHost section with `SetEnv GEM_HOME "/path/to/gemset"`. Set both GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME (you can get them with `rvm info`)

Comment: not sure how to do a 'SetEnv' in nginx, can I do that in boot.rb also?

Comment: rails console on the server, require 'bundler' doesn't throw an error

Comment: I haven't used nginx, so I'm not sure how its done. I doubt that it will consider your .rvmrc, but you should be able to export GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH in whatever script you use to start nginx (or thin, god, ect...)

Comment: Can't figure out where to set GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH, I setup my server as per: http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/a-guide-to-a-nginx-passenger-and-rvm-server